# How to build and use Mosby library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mosby

I try to add [Mosby library](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) to my pet project, but i cannot understand how to include it to project?
I try to add mosby by add as module-> add as Gradle project, but it not compile.

please, can you link me some tutorial how to add projects (source) into my project and how to use it then (i mean a access to libs classes from my code)?

Thank you!

P.S.  Project stores at K:\PetProject. Mosby at: K:\mosby.

settings.gradle (of my project):

```
 include ':app', ':mvp', ':sample-dagger2-rx', ':sample', ':mvp-common', ':viewstate', ':sample-kotlin', ':sample-flow', ':testing', ':sample-mail', ':sample-dagger1'
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all    sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta7'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files



  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle at myproject\app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.simplevolk.mafiagm"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/2'] } }
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

[image: Here is project structure]

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're having difficulties with without seeing your gradle file, but if I'm reading you right, you are trying to add it as a project? You need to add them as dependencies. You may want to refer to http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/ for help getting started.

Comment: @user4989692 , i want to use mosby in my project, but i do not know how to include it

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your gradle file where you added mosby?

Comment: @user4989692, edit post with gradle files and image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mosby should be added to your project by adding the following to the `dependencies` section in your `build.gradle` at `myproject\app` rather than as a module as how you did it.

```
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.1'
compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:viewstate:2.0.1' // optional viewstate feature
```

As for a tutorial for using Mosby, the [url at the top of the Mosby github page](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/) links to information about the library including a tutorial about how to use it. I found the walk through of the sample-mail app at http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/first-app/ helpful when I started using Mosby.

Comment: Thanks! You might want to change to the `implementation` keyword as `compile` is deprecated now.